# Node-inspector not showing all files

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, node-inspector

I run my app in debug mode:

```
killall -9 node
node-inspector & nodemon --debug server.js
```

This is my output:

```
[2] 12093
Node Inspector v0.12.5
[nodemon] 1.8.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858 to start debugging.
Debugger listening on port 5858
Magic happens on port 8080
```

When I navigate my app, I get a node-inspector notice that my breakpoint has been hit but clicking the notification does nothing and when i navigate to node-inspector tab, there's no line to indicate that it's at my breakpoint and typing anything in console doesn't show that either.

Node-inspector is only showing my express routes file which is my first and second required files. It is not showing any other files available.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being as simple as fixing the permissions on my node-inspector and nodemon commands:

```
sudo chown 'whoami' /usr/local/bin/node-inspector
```

Comment: Unfortunately this issue came back even with setting permissions.

Comment: did u find any solution to this going through the same